# How can I remove line breaks from lines that only start with a specific character in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, string, replace, split

I am trying to remove line breaks from a string that only begin with a specific character and am having trouble finding a solution. In my scenario I'm am trying to remove all line breaks where the line starts with a quotation mark. Heres an example:

Input:

```
`
Test
"How" +
"Can" +
"I" +
Do This?
`;
```

Desired Result:

```
`
Test "How" + "Can" + "I"
Do This?
`;
```

I've only been able to find a way to remove all line breaks. Still unable to find a solution to only remove them if a conditional is met.

Comment: Use a regular expression with a lookahead.

Comment: None of the lines begin with a quotation mark. They begin with a bunch of spaces followed by a quotation mark.

Comment: Why didn't you remove the newline before `"How"`? That line begins with a quotation mark.

Comment: Good catch, I fixed it to how it should be in my scenario. Ill look up using a regex with lookahead. Thank you

Comment: `str.replace(/\n\s?"/g, ' "').replace(/\+\n/g, '\n')`

Comment: The input has three `+`, while the output has two. Is that part of the intended logic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just match the quote as well -- there's even no need for a regex:

```js
let s = `
Test
"How" +
"Can" +
"I" +
Do This?
`;

s = s.replaceAll('\n"', ' "');
console.log(s);
```

In your question you have also removed  `+` before a new line character. If that was intended, and all such  `+` should be removed, then:

```js
let s = `
Test
"How" +
"Can" +
"I" +
Do This?
`;

s = s.replaceAll('\n"', ' "').replaceAll(" +\n", "\n");
console.log(s);
```

Comment: Thanks so much, I didn't even think to just replace the code. This works great.